# Links to files outside a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

A stupid newbie question: I want to make a PostgreSQL (9.2.2 with PostGIS 2.0.1; on 32-bit Windows XP) database with rasters saved outside the database (I will need the rasters to be accessed from outside the database and they won't be uploaded/migrated frequently, so consistence is not an issue). My problem is: I don't know how to make the links to the rasters (from database with metadata), and I didn't find anything comprehensible enough.

I have found something about [data wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html), but they seem to be intended for data with table structure, not files like rasters. DATALINK seems better, but I'm afraid it's the same case, plus I'm not sure I understood how to use it. In some of the discussions I've found a mention of symbollic links, but these seem to be something Unix-based, and probably only vaguely related.

I'm sure it must be simple, but I didn't manage to solve it myself.

Comment: What's a "raster"? I guess you just want to save path + file name as `text`.

Comment: I think that that can cause many potential bugs, e.g. inconsistency of files. What if somebody changes name or location of files without any modification in db?

Comment: @Borys: there would be few changes on the server, which means few opportunities for mistakes. While some of the files are quite big (even hundreds of megabytes, though most are smaller, just megs) and they will be accessed from outside the database, this is definitely the better solution than to store them in the database. Extra care from time to time is a small price for better performance on everyday tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases provide no possibilities to link outside objects.

I can think of at least 2 approaches:

1. Save a full path to your files in some metadata table as one of the attributes or type `text`. Don't use it for joining tables in queries though, having artifitial key of internal numeric type (like `integer` or `bigint`) is a better choice for performance reasons;
2. Name your raster files according to their numeric keys in the database. This approach has a drawback — without database you will not be able to obtain any usefull info about your files.

Further paths depends on the complexity of your system and choosen optimization techniques.

Comment: The "large objects" interface can be seen as a "link" to an outside object.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, but it also makes object to be kept inside the database, so it is not quite a link to an *external* thing.